# Use pandas to determine how many of the previous rows are required to sum to a threshold

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame and I would like to create a new column `desired_col`, which contains the required number of rows in `col1` to sum >= a threshold value.

For example if I choose my threshold value to be 10 and I have

```
d = {'col1': [10,1,2,6,1,6,4,3,2,3,1,1,4,5,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
display(df)
```

What I would like to end up with is

```
new_d = {'col1': [10,1, 2,6,1,6,4,3,2,3,1,1,4,5,5], 'desired_output':[0,1,2,3,3,2,1,2,3,3,4,4,4,2,1]}
new_df = pd.DataFrame(data=new_d)
display(new_df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will produce your desired output:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [10,1,2,6,1,6,4,3,2,3,1,1,4,5,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

target = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    element = df.iloc[i].col1
    print(element)
    s = element
    threshold = 10
    j=i
    steps = 0
    while s < threshold:
        j -= 1
        steps += 1
        if j < 0:
            steps = None
            s = threshold + 1
        else:
            s += df.iloc[j].col1
    target.append(steps)
df["desired_output"] = target
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. I was hoping there would be a way to better leverage pandas to save on time, but this does the job if necessary. Cheers.